# Postgres Data to XML

Tags: xml, postgresql

Does anyone know any good methods for converting database entries into XML?

I.e. if i have a table named "Users" with fields "first_name", "age", "last_name", I'd like to convert the table to:

```
<Users>
  <first_name>Papa</first_name>
  <age>50</age>
  <last_name>John</last_name>
</Users>
```

Answer (score 26):

In PostgreSQL you could it like this:

```
SELECT table_to_xml('users', true, false, '');
```

Or

```
SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT * FROM users', true, false, '');
```

There are other options as well, just check [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html).

Comment: where will be the generated xml file location? Is there any default path exists?

Comment: @Haji There is no file location, just a result set from this query. You could use COPY to dump the file somewhere, COPY takes the filename and location as an input parameter.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while but what does do **true,false,''** ? 
Also when I **COPY** this output, there are a lot of **\n** chars. How can I remove these **\n** chars?

Comment: Can you also do query_to_xml on a CTE?

Comment: To use xml feature in postgres, Postgres server must be first compiled with libxml library.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question independent of the DB it can be done with any DB supported by `ActiveRecord`.

```
User.find(some_id).to_xml(:except => [:id,:created_at,:updated_at])
```

The `:except => [:id,:created_at,:updated_at]` removes the Rails default columns from the XML output.

There is an interesting blog post about this matter: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/4/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-a-more-flexible-to_xml

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Jigfox.  I probably shouldn't have tagged Rails with this questions.  But what if, Rails isn't installed in the system?