# Dump postgresql table to XML file

Tags: sql, xml, database, postgresql

so this is a relatively simple question. I have a postgresql table which I need to dump to an xml file on my local machine. I've read all the documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html and I have come up with the following command through the psql command line:

```
COPY (SELECT table_to_xml(SELECT FROM Database public.'table', true, false, '')) to 'C:/users/me/file.xml';
```

However I keep getting a syntax error at or near the "FROM". I have searched for the past hour through every SO link that looked useful ([Postgresql tables exists, but getting "relation does not exist" when querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753568/postgresql-tables-exists-but-getting-relation-does-not-exist-when-querying) | [Cannot simply use PostgreSQL table name ("relation does not exist")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695289/cannot-simply-use-postgresql-table-name-relation-does-not-exist) | [using copy in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472303/using-copy-in-postgresql) | [Postgres Data to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559909/postgres-data-to-xml)) and every YouTube video that sounded remotely like what I needed, but to no avail. I've tried with and without the FROM statement, tried with a SELECT * in front of the FROM, etc... no luck. There must be something terribly simple I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the output for :  SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name = 'your_table_name'

Comment: Curious, does `table_to_xml()` query work before even copying to text file?

Comment: @Vivek When I execute the query SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name = 'your_table_name' on my PGAdmin 4 I get the following results: A table with quite a few headers that has one row. The headers are table_catalog (Database Name), table_schema (public), table_name (Name of My Table), table_type (BASE TABLE), etc... the rest are null

Comment: Instead of giving public as database name put the value that’s returns as database, it’s all are try as I don’t have pg session right now

Comment: @Vivek So good news and bad news... Good news is I tried as you suggested to execute the command COPY (SELECT table_to_xml(Database.'table', true, false, '')) to 'C:/users/me/file.xml'; And it did not give me an error... however no file was created, and by the looks of my Task manager nothing else is happening.

Comment: Can u specify the some other drive path like D:\abc.csv

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it seems the syntax is wrong, which you tried.

```
COPY (SELECT table_to_xml('table', true, false, '')) to 'C:/users/me/file.xml';
```

Alternative, you can try:

```
psql -p5432 db_name \copy (SELECT table_to_xml('table', true, false, '')) TO 'C:/users/me/file.xml';
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but I have already tried this. I get the error that that relation does not exist when it does. That is why I added the Database public.'table' portion to the original query. If I try COPY (SELECT table_to_xml(Database public.'table', true, false, '')) to 'C:\users\me\file.xml'; I get a syntax error at or near 'public'

Comment: can you use 'public.table' instead

Comment: I have also added one more way to do the same, using "psql" command this also works.

Comment: I have attempted both of your suggestions to no avail. I am still getting the error that the relation does not exist. I have triple checked that it is spelled correctly and typed exactly in the case I created it in... I don't understand how it still cannot find the relation. Is there perhaps some setting in the PGAdmin tool I could set to make it recognize the relation?

Answer (score 0):

OK so update. After spending the majority of my day struggling with this I have come up with a partial solution. Using information from here and [Permission denied when trying to import a CSV file from PGAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083311/permission-denied-when-trying-to-import-a-csv-file-from-pgadmin) I was able to get a command to work in PGAdmin 4 sort of...

```
COPY (SELECT table_to_xml('table_name', true, false, '')) to 'C:\XML\Table.xml';
```

The above command when run in PGAdmin will apparently do something I only assume is what I want. I have not had time to check if it actually creates a working XML file of the table if I use a smaller dataset. Yet if I follow the instructions in the before mentioned link and create a folder with a blank XML file in it and set the permissions to allow everyone to read/write to the folder the command executes. However it uses an obscene amount of memory. To write a table which is only around 2GB in size to XML the program consumed all 36GB of my memory before crashing itself. I don't have time to continue testing this, because I found that I could get to where I needed to be using a dump to a text file. anyway I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The copy-statement doesn't work for me - runs out of RAM. 
Exporting with C# works fine, though (this still loads all data into memory):

```
public static void DataToXML()
{
    Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    csb.Database = "YourDB";
    csb.Host = "localhost";
    csb.Port = 5432;
    csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    csb.Username = "postgres";
    // csb.Password = "";


    using (System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable())
    {

        dt.TableName = "record";

        using (System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet("geoip_blocks_temp"))
        {
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            // dt.Namespace = "foo";

            using (System.Data.Common.DbConnection con = Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory.Instance.CreateConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = csb.ConnectionString;

                using (System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM geoip.geoip_blocks_temp";

                    using (System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter da = Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory.Instance.CreateDataAdapter())
                    {
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                        if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                            con.Open();

                        da.Fill(dt);

                        if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                            con.Close();
                    } // End Using da 

                } // End Using cmd 

            } // End Using con 


            //using (System.IO.Stream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"D:\geoip_blocks_temp.xml"))
            //{
            //    using (System.IO.TextWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            //    {
            //        // System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            //        // dt.WriteXml(sw, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
            //        dt.WriteXml(sw, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
            //    } // End Using sw 

            //} // End Using fs 


            System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xs = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
            xs.Indent = true;
            xs.IndentChars = "    ";
            xs.NewLineChars = System.Environment.NewLine;
            xs.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
            // xs.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; // doesn't work with pgsql 
            xs.Encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);

            // <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
            using (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(@"D:\geoip_blocks_temp.xml", xs))
            {
                dt.WriteXml(writer, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows.Count);
        } // End Using ds 

    } // End Using dt 

} // End Sub DataToXML
```

Or more memory-conserving:

```
public static void LargeDataToXML()
{
    string table_schema = "geoip";
    string table_name = "geoip_blocks_temp";

    // table_schema = "public";
    // table_name = "t_sys_language_monthnames";


    System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xs = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
    xs.Indent = true;
    xs.IndentChars = "    ";
    xs.NewLineChars = System.Environment.NewLine;
    xs.OmitXmlDeclaration = false; // // <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    // xs.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; // doesn't work with pgsql 
    xs.Encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);

    string exportFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"d:\", table_name + ".xml");

    using (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(exportFilename, xs))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement(table_name);

        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace);
        // writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", null, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace);



        using (System.Data.Common.DbConnection con = Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory.Instance.CreateConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = GetCS();

            using (System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + table_schema + "." + table_name;


                if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Open();

                using (System.Data.Common.DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                {

                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        int fc = dr.FieldCount;

                        string[] columnNames = new string[fc];
                        // System.Type[] columnTypes = new System.Type[fc];

                        for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; ++i)
                        {
                            columnNames[i] = dr.GetName(i);
                            // columnTypes[i] = dr.GetFieldType(i);
                        } // Next i 

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            // object[] thisRow = new object[dr.FieldCount];

                            writer.WriteStartElement("record");

                            for (int i = 0; i < fc; ++i)
                            {
                                writer.WriteStartElement(columnNames[i]);
                                object obj = dr.GetValue(i);

                                if (obj != System.DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                    writer.WriteValue(obj);
                                }
                                else
                                    writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "nil", System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace, "true");

                                writer.WriteEndElement();
                            } // Next i

                            writer.WriteEndElement();

                        } // Whend 

                    } // End if (dr.HasRows) 

                } // End Using dr 

                if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Close();
            } // End Using cmd 

        } // End Using con 

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    } // ENd Using writer 

} // End Sub LargeDataToXML
```